# Как остановить цикл while?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

Всем привет, мне нужна помощь, как остановить цикл в нужном мне странице.
Заранее спасибо

```
while True:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-last').click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "a-last")))
    time.sleep(3)
    links.append(driver.current_url)
```

Comment: `break` - инструкция выхода из цикла. Скомбинируйте с каким-либо условием.

Comment: ели возможно скажи как именно. я учусь поэтому не знаю как, мне нужно что бы оно остановился на последнем странице.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, ссылку на сайт, который Вы пытаетесь парсить, и я постараюсь Вам помочь.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=galaxy+s10&qid=1566548375&ref=sr_pg_1

Comment: Вы слишком усложняете процесс. Вы можете получить необходимую страницу, добавив параметр `page` к `GET`-запросу. То есть, Вам нужно узнать, сколько всего страниц (спарсить цифру с классом `a-disabled`), а потом просто запросить нужную. На примере ссылки выше, добавьте в конец `URL` `&page=20`.

Comment: Большое спасибо вам.